# re-focus UItextfield after rotation of device

Tags: ios, keyboard-events, reloaddata

I am reloading my table with **reloaddata** on rotation of device in my app. If a **UITextfield** is focused before rotation and keyboard is open , I want it to stay focused and keyboard remains open. **Reloaddata** calls "**textfieldshouldEndEditing**" and "**KeyboardshouldHide**" notifications and thus on rotation my textfield is not focused and keyboard is also closed.

To achieve this I am using the following code:

```
[myTextfield performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)
                                     withObject:nil
                                     afterDelay:1.0f];
```

This works fine and keyboard opens again after rotating the device but the problem is when I press *keyboard hide button* (now keyboard is closed) and then rotate the device, Keyboard is still showing up which is wrong as before rotating the device I closed it.

Can someone suggest what is wrong or what should be done to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you before the rotation if the keyboard is visible you it and schedule it to present in 1 second.
I guess the problem is that you schedule the keyboard to present even if it is hidden. If that is the case you should check if the keyboard is visible before `performSelector: withObject:afterDelay:`

```
if ([myTextField isFirstResponder]) {
    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [myTextField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.];
}
```

Although I really don't think `performSelector: withObject:afterDelay:` is the proper way of doing it. You might want to use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` methods instead. You can store the reference to the `textField` or any other `firstResponder` (i.e. if you have multiple `textField`s or `textView`s:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ([self.myTextFiled isFirstResponder]) {
        self.toBeFirstResponderAfterInterfaceOrientationChange = self.myTextFiled;
        [self.myTextFiled resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (self.toBeFirstResponderAfterInterfaceOrientationChange) {
        [self.toBeFirstResponderAfterInterfaceOrientationChange becomeFirstResponder];
        self.toBeFirstResponderAfterInterfaceOrientationChange = nil;
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     self.toBeFirstResponderAfterInterfaceOrientationChange = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a BOOL class variable like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
   hasKeyboardOpen = YES;
}

// your own method to hide keyboard you would call when user physically hide keyboard
- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];

    hasKeyboardOpen = NO;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(hasKeybaordOpen == YES)
    {
        [myTextfield performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)
                                     withObject:nil
                                     afterDelay:1.0f];
    }
}
```